# Unable to run docker container for mongodb 2.6.12

Tags: mongodb, docker, containers

I need mongodb specific version and when I run the following command, it runs the container but exit quickly

```
docker run --name some-mongo -d mongo:2.6.12

4bbe88021ad919ba9680a2a4710e664a87e8620d4cd9802567029fec131534a3
```

If I list the containers `docker ps -a`, I can see following output

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                       PORTS                                                       NAMES
4bbe88021ad9   mongo:2.6.12      "/entrypoint.sh mong…"   4 seconds ago   Exited (139) 3 seconds ago                                                               some-mongo
```

I am not sure why its existing and hence tried the logs

`docker logs 4bbe88021ad9` but the is result **empty** (no result at all)

**Please note the lates version works fine**

`docker run -p 27031:27017 --name kongoLatest -d mongo`

I need to investiage why its not working for specific version? The main process must be failing and throwing some error which I am not able to see it.

Comment: Tried running it in interactive mode? `docker run -it --rm mongo:2.6.12`

Comment: Look like you are using Docker on Mac M1, so version `2.6.12` is failing on Mac M1 but it is not failing on Intel processor. On my Intel it is working, but on Mac M1 it is giving error.  So to dig out, error: `failed to create new OS thread (have 2 already; errorno=221)` is clearly comming in log. If you are deploying on Intel droplets you won't get issue their. But currently I don't see any reasonable solution.  here explained https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6137

Comment: @KamalPanhwar I am trying to run it on windows 10 my local machine (Docker Desktop), plain docker nothing fancy here.

Comment: @Phil its still the same exit immediately without any errors

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by fancy. For Windows sorry I can't say anything as never used windows from ages.